# pandas data frame append to the google sheet

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-sheets, append

Hello im using the following code for appending my pandas dataframe to my google sheet but the problem is instead of the row being appending to the end of the previous rows the dataframe gets appended to the end of the google sheet.

`````
            existing = gd.get_as_dataframe(ws,usecols=[0,1])
            existing
            updated = existing.append(orphaned_boxes)
            gd.set_with_dataframe(ws,updated,include_column_header = True,resize=True)
    ````
`````

Comment: You need to include more of your code.